# when constructing, how to know if object is daughter class

Tags: c++

```
class A {
    A();
};

class B : A {
    B();
};

A::A(){
    //A file is parsed here, but if B is created, we don't need to parse.
    //How to check here if 'this' will be B or A;
}

B::B():A(){

}

int main(){ 
    B b;
}
```

I would like to know, in the constructor, if the object is a child class or not.
I have already tried to call `dynamic_cast` to child class, but looks like it doesn't work.

Comment: Why would the base class need to know or care about that?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, base classes knowing anything about their subclasses is a big no-no. Could you elaborate on what problem you are trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: What do the "Some instructions" do?

Comment: The only way to do that would be providing such info to constructor externally, e.g. by passing an argument saying "you are called from B" (and ensuring that all `B` constructors do pass that argument).

Comment: If `B` doesn't need the parsed file, then it really isn't an `A`.  Inheritance implies an is-a relationship.

Comment: whatever you want to do in A constructor when constructing a `B` you can do in `B`s constructor as well

Comment: You could pass in a parameter to `A` to notify `A` whether or not it is being constructed as part of a child class.  `A(bool part_of_a_child_class);`

Comment: "...but if B is created, we don't need to parse." this sounds like bad design. Maybe `B` isnt a `A` in the first place. Maybe `B` should not inherit from `A`. Perhaps `A` is doing too much and `B` only wants to inherit some of it, then the problem to be fixed is that `A` is doing to much

Comment: Inside `A::A()` the object pointed to by `this` is always `A`.  The constructor is not told that your `A` will later become the base class of another type.

Comment: There are many comments about how what you are trying would be a bad design, which I concur. Just 1 additional word: the first thing the constructor `B` does is call constructor `A`. As such, the comment you left in the constructor `A` "*if B is created*" is a non-sense. `B` is simply not created/constructed yet when you are in the middle of constructor `A`.

Comment: Core Guidelines suggests factory functions: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-factory

Comment: What if there are other things that `A` may not do, depending on `B`?  Right now you are showing just parsing the file, then later on, you want to do something else that `A` shouldn't do depending on `B`.  Do you see what this will lead to?  An endless amount of `bool` variables or similar, with no indication what `bool` means what.  Maybe instead, create another class (call it `FeaturesOfA`) that turns on/off certain aspects of `A`.  Then `A` queries that class and knows exactly what or what not to do.  Then have `B` pass that instance to `A` on construction.

Comment: This sounds like a design problem, not something to solve with coding tricks. It should be three classes, not two. `A` should provide appropriate services for its derived classes; `B`, derived from `A`, can be whatever it is now; `C`, also derived from `A`, should parse the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Not even with `dynamic_cast`.

While an object of type `T` is being constructed (ie: the duration of its constructor), it is exactly and *only* of type `T`. If the object being made is for some class `U` which is derived from `T`, the `U` will only be constructed *after* the `T` base class is (successfully) constructed.

So during `T`'s constructors, it is *not yet* a `U`. During that period, *nobody* knows that a `U` is going to be constructed, so there's no mechanism to determine that. Even `virtual` functions, during the constructor of `T`, will point to `T`'s versions of those functions, not the `U` versions. Because again, it's not a `U` yet.

You need to reassess whether this type should be a base class *at all*.